# Two men set out at the same time to walk towards each other from $M$ and $N$, $72$ miles apart. The first man walks at the rate of $4$ mph

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Help with this problem please :-

> Two men set out at the same time to walk towards each other from $M$ and $N$, $72$ miles apart. The first man walks at the rate of $4$ mph. The second man walks $2$ miles the first hour, $2\tfrac {1}{2}$ miles the second hour, $3$ miles the third hour, and so on in arithmetic progression. Then the men will meet:

$\textbf{(A)}\ \text{in 7 hours} \qquad  \textbf{(B)}\ \text{in }{8\frac {1}{4}}\text{ hours}\qquad  \textbf{(C)}\ \text{nearer }{M}\text{ than }{N}\qquad\\  \textbf{(D)}\ \text{nearer }{N}\text{ than }{M}\qquad \textbf{(E)}\ \text{midway between }{M}\text{ and }{N}$

Total distance= 72 = $D_{A} +D_{B}$  $\to$
                72= 4T +$D_{B}$

$D_{B}= (2+2.5+3+3.5+....)T$

Now what should i do ?

Comment: Please share what you have attempted and indicate where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see how much they move together each hour; for the first hour it's $4$ miles + $2$ miles, then for the second hour it's $4$ miles + $2.5$ miles etc. Combine it:

$$(4+2) + (4+2.5) + (4+3) + (4+3.5)\ ... = 6 + 6.5 + 7 + 7.5 + \ ...$$

Now we know that each term added is one hour elapsed, this means that when this sum equals $72$ (i.e. the whole distance they were apart); then the number of terms must equal the number of hours it has taken them to move the $72$ miles together.

A sum for an arithmetic series is $S = ns + d\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, where $s$ is the starting term, and $d$ is the difference between terms. Plug in for $s = 6$ and $d = 0.5$ and we get that:

$$6 + 6.5 + 7 + 7.5 + \ ... = 6n +  \frac{0.5n(n-1)}{2} = \frac{23n + n^2}{4}$$

Now as we said, when that sum is equal to $72$ then the entire distance has elapsed. Each term is one hour so we just need to solve for $n$:
$$\frac{23n + n^2}{4} = 72$$
$$(n+11.5)^2 = 288 + (11.5)^2$$
$$n + 11.5 = \frac{41}{2}$$
$$n = 9$$

When they've traveled for $9$ hours, they will have gone the entire $72$ miles. If we see how many miles the first person has walked by then ($4$ miles per hour) it's $4 * 9 = 36$ miles. Which is half the distance. This means that the other one walks $72 - 36 = 36$ miles as well, so the correct answer is **(E)**.

Comment: Fabulous  solution  , thanks a lot